# rails practice for helper_method and instance variable (current_user)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi i'm freshman to Ruby on Rails.
I'm trying to make current_user method and i have a question.
Many Rails courses make current_user method like this.

```
  helper_method current_user

  def current_user
    @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]
  end
```

This method stores current user in instance variable.
But in view file, most of course use method in view like this.

```
  <% if current_user %>
  ...
  <% end %>
```

I'm wondering why "store current user in instance variable" good right practice, even we will not use instance variable in view file.
I'm still lacking in skills, so I have this question, so please take good care of me. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**It's called memoization** - a common practice used to speed up applications.

How it works: you are evaluating some expression just one time and cache value in memory to use any number of times further. You can find a lot information about it and I would recommend to check it, example:

https://www.honeybadger.io/blog/ruby-rails-memoization/

**In your case**

The first time you call `current_user` method, instance variable `@current_user` is `nil` so you:

1. proceed authentication (`User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]`);
2. save user in `@current_user`.

Next time you call `current_user` you:

3. will get the value which is saved in `@current_user` (and authentication will not be proceeded).

`Current user` is something that will not be changed during the request. But if you wouldn't store `user` in instance variable there would be a database request (step 1 - proceed authentication) every time you call `current_user` method which is considered to be pretty time-expensive.